# C# fill combo box with postgreSQL select using Npgsql then populate other textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, npgsql

I am using the Npgsql assembly.

I have code which fills a datagridview with the results from a SQLquery, I also want it to populate a combobox at the same time and then once the selection is made the other two text boxes are populated with the two other fields of the same rows value.

controlp contains 3 fields:

```
com pri not
add 1   adds a file
del 2   deletes a file
ame 3   amends a file
```

Just for info the connection string is stored in another class.

Current code which fills the datagridview:

```
string pquery = "SELECT * FROM controlp";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Utils.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand pcmd = new NpgsqlCommand(pquery, conn);
NpgsqlDataAdapter pda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
pda.SelectCommand = pcmd;
DataTable pdt = new DataTable();
pda.Fill(pdt);
pDGV.DataSource = pdt;
conn.Close();
```

I created two combo boxes to hold the selected index values before they are put into the text boxes for example if I select a value in the `comComboBox`, `add` for example, I want it to populate `notComboBox` with 'adds a file' and `priComboBox` with `1` as they are in the same row.

I have tried this code but I am getting an error when I make a selection in the comComboBox:

```
string pquery = "SELECT * FROM controlp";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Utils.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand pcmd = new NpgsqlCommand(pquery, conn);
NpgsqlDataAdapter pda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
pda.SelectCommand = pcmd;
DataTable pdt = new DataTable();
pda.Fill(pdt);
pDGV.DataSource = pdt;
for (int i = 0; i < pdt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        comComboBox.Items.Add(pdt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
    }
conn.Close();
private void comComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        priComboBox.SelectedIndex = notComboBox.SelectedIndex = comComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        notTextBox.Text = notComboBox.Text;
        priTextBox.Text = priComboBox.Text;
    }
```

Error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
>   Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Comment: How do you fill the _notComboBox_ ? Does it contain some data? (same question for the other one _priComboBox_)

Comment: Thats the issue, When i select a value in the comComboBox, `add` for example, i want it to populate notComboBox with 'adds a file' and priComboBox with `1` as they are in the same row.

Comment: What are you trying to do? : priComboBox.SelectedIndex = notComboBox.SelectedIndex = comComboBox.SelectedIndex;

Comment: See comment above When i select a value in the comComboBox, add for example, i want it to populate notComboBox with 'adds a file' and priComboBox with 1 as they are in the same row

Comment: @Matt but they don't have any item added so setting the SelectedIndex to 0 is invalid. You need to fill these combos with the list of items as you do for the first one. Of course these combos will show a different column of your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the whole row retrieved from the database directly in a single ComboBox. In this context you should provide your combobox with the information on what is the property to use to display in its list and text.
The best approach is to define a class that 'models' your database table, then fill a list of this table with instances created while you loop over the results.

```
public class ControlP
{
    public string Com {get;set;}
    public int Pri { get; set; }
    public string Not {get;set;}
}
......
List<ControlP> results = new List<ControlP>();
string pquery = "SELECT * FROM controlp";

// Don't forget to enclose the connection in a using statement. It is a 
// disposable object and should be correctly destroyed when you finish to use it
using(NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Utils.ConnectionString))
using(NpgsqlCommand pcmd = new NpgsqlCommand(pquery, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(NpgsqlDataReader reader = pcmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
             ControlP p = new ControlP();
             p.Com = reader["com"].ToString();
             p.Pri = Convert.ToInt32(reader["pri"]);
             p.Not = reader["not"].ToString();
             results.Add(p);
        }
        pDGV.DataSource = results;
        comComboBox.DataSource = results;
        comComboBox.DisplayMember = "Com";
        comComboBox.ValueMember = "Pri";
    }
}
```

At this point you could use the SelectedIndexChanged event to retrieve the selected object and read its properties without the other two combos.

```
private void comComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ControlP p = comComboBox.SelectedItem as ControlP;
        notTextBox.Text = p.Not;
        priTextBox.Text = p.Pri;
    }     
}
```

Remember that when you set the DataSource you cannot use the Items collection. You should always add/delete/remove elements from the underlying combo's datasource

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by adding the add rows for the other two ComboBoxs.

```
string pquery = "SELECT * FROM controlp";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Utils.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand pcmd = new NpgsqlCommand(pquery, conn);
NpgsqlDataAdapter pda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
pda.SelectCommand = pcmd;
DataTable pdt = new DataTable();
pda.Fill(pdt);
pDGV.DataSource = pdt;
for (int i = 0; i < pdt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        comComboBox.Items.Add(pdt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
        priComboBox.Items.Add(pdt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
        notComboBox.Items.Add(pdt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
    }
conn.Close();
private void comComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        priComboBox.SelectedIndex = notComboBox.SelectedIndex = comComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        notTextBox.Text = notComboBox.Text;
        priTextBox.Text = priComboBox.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Well this will work of course but you should really use just one combo and fill its DataSource property as you do with the grid. Then use the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties to choose what to display in each combo.

Comment: @Steve How would i do that? I'm always open to better ways of doing things

Comment: I have added an answer to highlight my idea.

Comment: @Steve I will try this